# Simpler proofs of necessary conditions for $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$, with $A, B \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

I was given the folllowing problem.

> Give necessary and sufficient conditions for $$(A+B)^2 = A^2 +2AB + B^2$$ $$A^2 - B^2 = (A+B)(A-B)$$
> to hold with $A, B \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to find the conditions than the one I used. What I did was the following.

---

For $C:=(A+B)^2$ we have $c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ik}+b_{ik})(a_{kj} + b_{kj})$ For $X:=A^2, Y:=2AB, Z:=B^2$ we have

$$x_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}$$
$$y_{ij}=2\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$$
$$z_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}b_{kj} $$

Then $(A+B)^2 = A^2+2AB+B^2 \iff c_{ij}= x_{ij}+y_{ij}+ z_{ij}$. This equation is equivalent to

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ik}+b_{ik})(a_{kj} + b_{kj}) &= \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj} + 2\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj} + \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}b_{kj} 
\end{align*}

Expanding the LHS we obtain

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=1}^n \Big(a_{ik}a_{kj}+a_{ik}b_{kj} + b_{ik}a_{kj}+b_{ik}b_{kj}\Big)   \\ 
    =\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}+\sum(a_{ik}b_{kj}+b_{ik}a_{kj})+\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}b_{kj}
\end{align*}

and then the equation becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}+\sum(a_{ik}b_{kj}+b_{ik}a_{kj})+\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj} + 2\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj} + \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}b_{kj}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ik}b_{kj}+b_{ik}a_{kj}) = 2\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$$

$$a_{ik}b_{kj}=b_{ik}a_{kj}$$

Since $a_{ik}b_{kj}=b_{ik}a_{kj} \iff A \cdot B = B \cdot A$ the necessary and sufficient condition for $(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$ is that $A \cdot B = B \cdot A$.

---

PD: Excuse the bad formatting. It seems the `\\` break for making new lines is not working, at least in my computer, so for every new line I had to create a new equation environment (which made alignment impossible).

Comment: Observe $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA$

Comment: That is exactly what comes right after "expanding the LHS we obtain (...)". I did the same operations that follow from your suggestion except that I wrote everything in terms of the scalars in the matrices, not of the matrices themselves (which seems a bit dumb now). For example, what's after "and then the equation becomes (...)" is what follows from your observation: $A^2+B^2+AB+BA = A^2+2AB +B^2 \iff AB = BA$.

Comment: I'm not trying to say your insight is not great, since it shows I could have written everything in a far more simpler manner. And I do thank you. But it is not really an alternative proof, in the sense that the reasoning is the same.

Comment: The difference is that you are trying to figure it out entry-by-entry, whereas you should really be working at the level of matrix multiplication, not how each entry is computed. You are missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: Further to the other comments' points, it looks like you came up with an entry-based proof due to not knowing matrix multiplication distributes over matrix addition. That has to be proved with entries, but then you can use it in future proofs. Indeed, it's a theorem whose usage doesn't usually need to be stated because, when it is used, people can tell that's what was used.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying all and I'm sorry for not having understood the point that was being made from the start. Very thankful to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer they were looking for is that it is necessary and sufficient for $A$ and $B$ to commute, for both equations $A^2-B^2 = (A-B)(A+B)$ and $(A+B)=A^2+2AB+B^2$ to hold.

Note that

$$(A+B)^2 = (A+B)(A+B)$$
$$=A^2 + AB+BA + B^2.$$

Then for the equation $A^2+AB+BA+B^2 = A^2+2AB+B^2$ to hold, simple algebra implies that the equation $AB=BA$ must hold. It is easy to see that this is a sufficient condition as well.

Likewise,

$$(A+B)(A-B) = A^2-AB+BA-B^2,$$
and for $A^2-AB+BA-B^2 = A^2-B^2$ to hold, it follows from simple algebra that the equation $AB=BA$ must hold. It is easy to see that this is a sufficient condition as well.

Comment: This is true in any ring.

Comment: @PaulFrost Surely not for a non-commutative ring?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout The necessary and sufficient condition is $AB=BA$, in any ring. If the ring is commutative, this it automatically satisfied.